# Assembly redirect for C++ (MFC, not .NET) application

Tags: c++, redirect, mfc

I'm trying to perform assembly redirection for an MFC application (not .NET application).
The MFC application and all external DLLs are fully isolated.
MyDLL is also written using MFC.

*Application.manifest* contains a dependency to

```
"MyDLL,version=1.0.0.0"
```

*MyDLL* has this assembly identity: `"MyDLL,version=2.0.0.0"`

*Application.exe.config* contains a redirection

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="MyDLL" culture="neutral" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but this redirection is not honored.
Is it possible to perform redirection for other than .NET runtime assemblies?
If not, are there some other way to perform redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All has been resolved using `<windows>` tag instead of `<runtime>`.